# How can I change multiple audio sources at once?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, html5-audio

I want to change with one click multiple source directories from multiple audio elements at once.

I'm trying to make a small 4-track player with a list of songs which one can choose from and listen to the stems of the selected song. This is the player so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="list-of-songs">
  <button id="song1" onclick="playsong1()">Song 1</button>
  <button id="song2" onclick="playsong2()">Song 2</button>
  <button id="song3" onclick="playsong3()">Song 3</button>
</div> 

<div class="multitrack__control-panel">
    <button id="pause" onclick="pause()"></button>
    <button id="play" onclick="play()"></button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stop()"></button>
        
    <audio id="track1" class="stem" src="audio/song1track1.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="track2" class="stem" src="audio/song1track2.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="track3" class="stem" src="audio/song1track3.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="track4" class="stem" src="audio/song1track4.wav"></audio>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var track1 = document.getElementById("track1");
var track2 = document.getElementById("track2");
var track3 = document.getElementById("track3");
var track4 = document.getElementById("track4");

/* Play */

function play() {
    track1.play();
    track2.play();
    track3.play();
    track4.play();
}

/* Pause */

function pause() {
  track1.pause();
  track2.pause();
  track3.pause();
  track4.pause();
}

/* Stop */

function stop() {
  track1.pause();
  track2.pause();
  track3.pause();
  track4.pause();
  track1.currentTime = 0;
  track2.currentTime = 0;
  track3.currentTime = 0;
  track4.currentTime = 0;
}
```

I am Javascript beginner, so I don't really know how to start doing the code for changing all the audio sources at the same time. I thought that using buttons to select the songs is good, but I have no problem in replacing them with an HTML List or something similar.

Comment: Your current setup isn't going to work for you, as the timing of each track is unpredictable.  You need to ensure you're playing these tracks at the exact same time.  For that, you need the Web Audio API.  As far as selecting multiple, the regular file input can do this for you.

Comment: @Brad While you are technically true about timings with the Web Audio API, there are other restrictions, which for example prevent me to use it for my own multitrack player. Depending on the the timing requirements, calling play() on the audio elements might be accurrately enough. You might have a look at my take on it at: https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa/blob/main/src/code/audio/MultitrackHandler.ts#L208

Comment: @Marcel What are the restrictions that you're running into?

Comment: @Brad Problem for me is memory consumption. I will have a lot of tracks (about 10 or more typically, of typical song lenght or more, in MP3). Precise timing with the Web Audio API is only possible with the buffered source, which is not recommended for lengths above 40 seconds. It uses fully decoded data. I expect my player to work on mobile phones.

Comment: @Brad I can sacrifice absolute synchronous playback precision up to maybe 16 milliseconds. That equals to about 5 meters separation on stage. It would be acceptable for musicians.

Comment: @Marcel You can use a ScriptProcessorNode to deliver the samples in a way that allows you to stream without loading everything into memory.  If you simply start a bunch of audio players, you can expect them to be much further apart than 16 milliseconds, especially if any of them have to go back to buffering.

Comment: @Brad That sounds interesting, but seems quite a bit of work to handle the streams/buffers itself. Also, it's deprecated in favor of AudioWorklets. Plus, the limitation there is CORS. Neither of the two will have access to the audio data when it's not served with the CORS headers.

Comment: It's not that much work, and you can use AudioWorklets if you prefer.  ScriptProcessingNodes are deprecated only because they don't want people using them for performance reasons.  It's unlikely they'll ever actually be removed or unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the source of an `<audio>`, just set the audio source in its `src` attribute:

```js
document.getElementById("track1").src = "path/audio.mp3";
```

In this case, you can change all those `<audio>` sources at the same time using a loop:

```js
const 
    sources = ["audio1.wav", "audio2.wav", "audio3.wav", "audio4.wav"],
    audioTags = document.querySelectorAll(".stem");

audioTags.forEach((audio, index) => audio.src = `audio/${sources[index]}`);
```

Basically I just set every element in the `sources` array as the source of each `<audio>`. I don't know what are you exactly want to do, but I think this could give you an idea on how to do it.